# How did Joseph become vizier under Pharaoh, an idol, without violating the prohibition against encouraging others to idol worship? Same Q for Esther

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, yosef

I'm definitely not suggesting either Joseph or Esther broke this prohibition (at all, or at worst unless it was necessary to save life or other exceptions granted by the Torah). I have little knowledge of the answer either way but assume the best. I only ask the question as a thought exercise to better understand the distinctions between when it is encouraging idol worship and when it isn't.

The pharaohs in Egypt considered themselves gods, and many in the population were ignorant, uneducated, poor, and believed it (or just idolatrous by nature regardless of those factors). Joseph became #2 in the nation, and had the attire to go with the position. How did he assume that title of vizier under those circumstances, and embody that position and all that went with it, without encouraging others in the court and the Egyptian citizens to idol worship him?

Same idea in Persia with Esther. In order to get Achashverosh to want to marry her, she may have had to look attractive and appeal to his physical, egoistic nature. At least, it seems like his type might have not seen her inner beauty most of the time, and that he might have looked at her as more than a trophy, in some sense an idol. He may have idolized her beauty and so on. So if his attention was of an idolatrous nature, then if she ever had to wear nice clothes and so on to keep his interest, did she encourage him to idol worship? (This is definitely not suggesting she did anything to bring any horrible treatment on herself, absolutely not, please do not misconstrue it that way. And everything she did was needed for the Jewish people to be saved. I only mean it as a way to ask the halachah question).

I also think it's a relevant question to today for anyone who works in the public domain in any type of job that is popular, that people will idolize. If you become the best violinist in the world, and you play publicly, there is going to be 1 out 10,000 or however many who comes to see you play, and is trying to learn themselves, who may come to idolize you (not always the same as idol worship but sometimes), and put pictures of you up all over their room, and make you a hero of their worship in some sense. Have you then encouraged idol worship? And that's not even a profession where the public nature of it has a really big "brand promotion" culture. What if you are an entrepreneur in such a business and you are promoting yourself and your "brand" via social media in order to build your business, and you sell a luxury lifestyle, and your personality and projecting an attractive image are central to promoting your business model? Have you encouraged idol worship?

I know there are certain exceptions for certain prohibitions, so I'm presuming that will be part of the answer, and I would also like to get into the distinctions of when being popular or powerful crosses the line into encouraging idol worship even in cases you don't have an exception because of a different category, if that makes sense, as well as into those distinctions and when they do and don't apply in such cases. Thank you/Toda rabah.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37738/27180

Comment: Are you sure that the sort of "Idolization" you refer to by Achashverosh and Yosef where really Avodah Zarah? Your example of idolizing a violinist is also up to debate - is it Avodah Zorah or just a hero worship (which I beleive is not considered avodah zorah, and therefore wouldnt go against the prohibition)

Comment: Esther did not try to attract attention, she did the *minimum* she had to until the day she had to ask for the Jews to be saved. It says so quite literally in the Megillah.

Comment: Halachic Idolization is different from what we might think is Idolization. Also Yosef was the #2 in Egypt. I doubt he had the time to encourage people to worship Idols or worship him. Think about it this way; does the Vice President of the US have much interaction with the public where she will be forced to do something against her will?
Also, it was Pharaoh who was worshipped but not the #2. As a matter of fact, I would think that Pharaoh would have made it extremely clear to everyone that him and only him was to be worshipped and not the #2 or a general or a priest.

Comment: The english word "idolization" is not equivalent to Avodah Zarah. So the Esther aspect isn't really a strong question. But the Yosef question is much stronger because Pharaoh did claim divinity. Yosef even "swore" on Pharaoh's life! How could he do that?

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizzaMonica I'm definitely not sure about that. I've heard it said that putting anything before G-d is idol worship, that there are people who idol worship their favorite sports player and stuff like that just by virtue of it being a central component in their lives. They don't think the player is a literal god but they still "idolize" him or her. And same concept with instagram models and social media. The definition of when such things are idol worship that is avodah zarah, and when it's halachally allowed "hero worship" (if not encouraged), is def relevant to answering.

Comment: To me this is a unanswerable question. You are asking how can we know something didn't happen which the text never states happened. Nowhere is it suggested that Joseph or Esther were worshiped as gods by anyone. As for the colloquial use of "idolizing" someone (i.e. admiring in excess), it does not translate to an actual halakhic category of עבודה זרה. Perhaps it could lead to idolatry, and fosters an idolatrous impulse, but there simply is no such overt prohibition. No one would ever be permitted to act admirably/exemplary were this the case (which it most evidently is not).

Comment: I cannot find (albeit I don't know anything) to define Avodah Zorah as anything but worshipping something as a god. If you have a source that says that this is not true, then maybe put it in the question. As @Deuteronomy states, the colloqiual idolatry is not idolatry. I have seen the idea that the way avodah zarah manifest nowadays is in these ideas of models/sports ect - but only as a hashkafic "one should avoid" not as halacha

Comment: @Deuteronomy Yeah that's a great point, it would sort of be impossible to excel at anything, unless you kept it a complete secret, were this the case. As for as it not being avodah zarah, is the prohibition only that you can't encourage outright acts of idolatry, or is the prohibition that you can't encourage an idolatrous impulse? Because encouraging an idolatrous impulse, even if not avodah zarah, can still lead to it in some people based on your encouragement. It will certainly lead to more of it than not at all. Im wondering how much we have to worry about influencing ANY negative impulses

Comment: @ShipBuilding I suggest reviewing Hilkhoth Avoda Zara in the Mishneh Torah to better understand its parameters, it is available in English online. As for doing an action which may lead others to sin, that is a separate prohibition of לפני עיוור לא תיתן מכשול (not placing a stumbling block before the blind), Negative Commandment 299 in Sefer ha-Miswoth. Generally speaking it concerns where one overtly/directedly leads a person astray.

Comment: @Deuteronomy Thanks a lot Deut. That helps me understand the general distinctions. If I think of a better example to ask about the grey area I am wondering about, I will respond again then, maybe later today but maybe not.

Comment: @ShipBuilding sure thing, no problem